# Is it possible to retrieve data from collectionViewCell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'm looking to retrieve data, such as a label.text from within a visible cell, and I don't know how that would be possible.

Plain context: I have a collectionView displaying questions (each cell display a question)
the collectionView is within a UIView.

Within this same uiview I have a button which, when pressed, should validate the question answer.
At this point the only thing Im doing is linking a @IBAction to the button in order for it to println the question from the visible cell (only one cell is visible).

here is how I construct the cell

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        return arr.count
        return questionData.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell

        let thereq:PFObject = self.questionData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

//        cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
        var action = thereq.objectForKey("action") as String
        var what = thereq.objectForKey("what") as String
        cell.askingQuestionLabel.text = "where \(action) \(what)"

        return cell
    }
```

on button touch (button is out of the cell).

I know `visibleCells()` exists but it doesn't look like I can retrieve info out of it.

```
        for cell in self.collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell] {

        }
```

Is there any way?

Comment: This question needs much more detail.  What object is the button on?  What's the IBAction tied to?  How does that class know about the cells?  How, in plain-English logic, would that class know which cell it should fetch data for?

Comment: This is basically what Im asking. I've updated my question

Comment: I still don't see how the button should know which cell to worry about.  Do you want it to handle every cell?

Comment: I would like the button to handle the visible cell (cell can be scrolled, only one visible at a time, and the button action take over the visible one). as said in the question, this is where Im lost. I saw that visibleCells() could be an option (see updated question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access data (such as a label.text) within a visible cell, you can use the visibleCells() method as follow:

```
for item in self.collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell] {
            var indexpath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(item as CollectionViewCell)!
            var cell : CollectionViewCell = self.collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath) as CollectionViewCell

            //access cell data
            println(cell.labelName.text)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a custom collection view cell class. The obvious solution is to pass the PFObject to the CollectionViewCell in your cellForItemAtIndexRow method, and then retrieve it from the cell when the button is clicked.

Just cast the return value from visibleCells to your collection view cell class and then pull the PFObject out of it.