# iOS Swift: animating CollectionViewCell elements from a button on the CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a button on a CollectionView that animates the labels on the CollectionView (slides them back & forth). I'm wondering if it's possible to also animate the labels on the cells using the same button.

I was considering collectionView:performAction as a possible solution, but I wanted to get some other ideas before sinking too much time into figuring out something that potentially might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo:

```
for item in self.collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell] {
        var indexpath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(item as CollectionViewCell)!
        var cell : CollectionViewCell = self.collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath) as CollectionViewCell

        //access cell data
        println(cell.labelName.text)
    }
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820397/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-data-from-collectionviewcell)